# Delete Contacts from 'All Contacts'

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact

We are trying to delete contacts from Marketing Cloud All Contacts. Is it sufficient to delete a contact from Sendable DE to delete it from All Contacts. Or do we need to call the Delete API?

Also, how do we delete data from Synchronized Data Extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacts can be deleted individually or by entire data extensions. From Contact Builder, click the All Contacts tab then select a contact and click the trash can icon on the top right of the page. To delete contacts in bulk, you can use a SQL activity to query contacts into a data extension to be deleted from here as well.

You can’t delete data from Synchronized Data Extensions, you need to delete from the CRM (Sales Cloud) then the next time the data is refreshed, they will be removed from your Synchronized Data Extension.

Comment: Does that mean I move contacts to a Data Extension, clear the data extension and contacts will be deleted from All Contacts? I don't have a need to call Delete Rest API.

Comment: That’s correct, as long as you delete them from the All Contacts tab in Contact Builder by selecting “Delete contacts from data extension”. Deleting the data extension from email studio for example will only delete the data extension and not the contacts in it.