# Deleting doubled subscribers on Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact-deletion

I have a problem as some subscribers have both Lead and Account records (with the same email address), likely due Lead Conversion Process.
This creates two separate records which mean two different sets of preferences and tracking data. Hence why my interest to purge part of the database.
Failure to do so will lead to many Subscribers with different preferences across their Lead/Contact record.
Majority of Subscribers (90%) have associated Salesforce CRM records.
The remainder of our Subscribers use Email Addresses for their key, when we investigated why such a high number of records were found using this identifier we found that 26K (86% of the records) already had an existing Subscriber records using Salesforce IDs. This is highly inefficient and results to disconnect between Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud tracking data.
Some Contacts have only email addresses as keys which mean they relate to no data within Salesforce CRM, this will make their data and engagement only visible to marketing team.

How can I cleanup of all Email Address key Subscribers which have matching Salesforce key records? As at the moment we are double-billed for no reasons.
Migration of “to be deleted” records to matching Salesforce records. Will this require engagement with Salesforce Account Executive?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating the duplicate records requires Salesforce support as they will be able to change subscriber keys based on matches from CRM.

You can delete the duplicate records yourself by running a SQL activity and then deleting them from all contacts in Contact Builder.

Explained in more detail here, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256853/43147

Hope this helps!